# Xenomai IPC buffers between realtime and non realtime threads

Tags: linux, pthreads, multitasking, xenomai

I've got a realtime application using Xenomai with the Alchemy skin, which has to communicate between the realtime and non realtime threads.

To do this I've created some buffers using `rt_buffer_create()` as described here:
https://doc.xenomai.org/v3/html/xeno3prm/group__alchemy__buffer.html
However, trying to read them from the non-realtime threads (pthreads) using `rt_buffer_read()` returns error code -EINVAL which should mean `bf is not a buffer descriptor, or len is greater than the actual buffer length`. I have confirmed that the buffer is being successfully created and the correct handle passed to `rt_buffer_read()`, and that the read length is less than the buffer length.

The documentation does not mention anything about not using the Xenomai IPC buffers in a non-realtime thread, however I am wondering if it is not possible or if there is something else that I might be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I've now solved this by creating the reading thread as a realtime task using rt_task_create and rt_task_start even though it does not need realtime capability and will likely get relaxed straight away when it calls the native posix functions.